# What is the best way to join two sculpted objects?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I have just finished a sculpt of my first head and neck in Blender which I did as two separate objects to be able to reposition at will.  As you can see in the wireframed pic the neck has quite some excess and unwanted mesh which I would like to eliminate to improve on the overall poly count.

[image]

**Which would be the best way to proceed to join the two sculpted objects and eliminate the excess mesh?**

I tried deleting the excess vertices in the neck's mesh and then simply join the two objects.  Once joined the deleted part was not visible at all. **However, with this method I cannot smooth the line between the neck and head**. **Keep in mind that I plan to simply paint the objects with marble texture and the main aim is to finally 3d print the face.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Why did I get this result when I did a Boolean Operation on the Neck and chose the head as the second object?**
The unwanted mesh on the neck was cut off as I wanted but the rest of the mesh resulted in a lot of disturbance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this with the *Boolean* modifier. Add a Boolean modifier to one of the objects you want to join, and set the operation to *union*. This will join the two meshes into non-overlapping meshes. You can then join the mesh without overlapping, disconnected vertices.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the result of the Boolean operation I tired was not so encouraging as you can see in my edited question above.

Comment: @ronin074 This is because your *Head object* is there twice. There's one rendered by the boolean modifier, and there's also the original one underneath. You need to disable it in outliner (uncheck the eye and camera icon). Then it will work just fine ;).